# Codeigniter - failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, image-uploading, codeigniter-3

I have a problem in upload picture in codeigniter
this is my view:

```
<form method="post" action="<? echo site_url('do_upload'); ?>" id="createForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />
        </div> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="picture" id="exampleInputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Choose file to upload.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</form>
```

my controller:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['picture']))
    { 
         $dossier = base_url().'assets/image/product/';
         $fichier = basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier)) //Si la fonction renvoie TRUE, c'est que ça a fonctionné...
         {
              echo 'Upload effectué avec succès !';
         }
         else //Sinon (la fonction renvoie FALSE).
         {
              echo 'Echec de l\'upload !';
         }
    }
}
```

and I have all time this problem:

[Screen shot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyCsz.png)

Comment: Have you checkd your upload folder permission?

Comment: No , how I check this folder ?

Comment: You can use your ftp client  connect to server right click on the folder and look for folder permissions

Comment: but i work my project in local , how can I look folder permission and change this permission in local ??

Comment: What do you work on Mac or pc

Comment: I m work in mac

Comment: $dossier = base_url().'assets/image/product/'; that is wrong. file upload function could not support http and https based url  you can remove the base_url(). please try  
$dossier = './assets/image/product/';
Hope it work if u working on Linux based os u need to set folder permmision 777

Comment: thank you very mush, is working ;)

Comment: right click on folder / get info /Sharing & Permissions

Comment: thanks :) :) :))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Upload function does not support HTTP & https based file path. also if you are used linux based os like ubuntu or mac to give the folder permission is 777 of all folder for ex. assets , image and product those three folder need read & write permission 777

```
public function do_upload()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['picture']))
    { 
         $dossier ='./assets/image/product/'; //based folder path if is inside public so u can use $dossier = './public/assets/image/product/';
         $fichier = basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier)) //Si la fonction renvoie TRUE, c'est que ça a fonctionné...
         {
              echo 'Upload effectué avec succès !';
         }
         else //Sinon (la fonction renvoie FALSE).
         {
              echo 'Echec de l\'upload !';
         }
    }
}
```